# TypeScript (ReactJS) compiler error, this implicitly has type any

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component written in TypeScript:

```
class App extends React.Component<props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.treeNavElement = this.treeNavElement.bind(this);
  }

  treeNavElement() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.NavDataTree.map(function(elem) {
            return <div key={elem.id} onClick={this.treeNavElement}>{elem.name}</div>
          }, this)
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

My problem is that the typescript compiler yells at me, because of this line:

```
return <div key={elem.id} onClick={this.treeNavElement}>{elem.name}</div>
```

Saying:

> [ts] 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

Outside of map function, in `map`'s second parameter and `this.props` it works fine, but inside `onClick` `this` is lost.

If I set `"noImplicitThis": false` in `tsconfig.json` it is fine, but I would like to know if there is a way around this without turning implicitthis off?

Comment: What if you use an arrow function?

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: What @Explosino Pills means is `...map((elem) => { ... })`

Comment: I know what he means, that doesn't change a thing about that `this` is unknown at compile time inside `map`. Again: this is a compile time issue, nuking `this` with `any` and zero issues at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, that is working for `this`, but now it has a different error.

Answer (score 2):

You use a `function`, so `this` is *lost*.

```
this.props.NavDataTree.map(function(elem) { })
```

You can type `this` if you know what this is at runtime `function(this: XXX) {}`. Or you can use the arrow operator, so `this` is propagate into the function

```
this.props.NavDataTree.map(elem => { this.XXX })
```

Comment: This is completely a compile time issue. If I suppress it with `noImplicitAny`, I have no runtime issues. I don't think `this` is lost. It would be in the callback function body, because of the this-binding rules, but inside `render()` it should be available because I specifically supplied `this` to the `thisArg` parameter of `map`. [From mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): _thisArg
Value to use as this when executing callback._
So `this` should be available at compile time inside map.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick fix, add the following line to tsconfig.js.

```
 "noImplicitThis": false,
```

> Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type.